# Split very large javascript file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm working on a web project that uses webgl content generated with unity. When trying to load the required js files the browser freezes for around 30 seconds. The main js file has 35MB size unzipped so this seems to be the cause.

I want to avoid this freeze if possible but I couldn't manage to do it using WebWorkers since the script needs access to UI. My other possible solution is to try to split the js file into smaller ones but I don't know how to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you could try to [Defer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) the script?

Comment: is the js file minified?

Comment: A **35MB** JavaScript file? That's well over a million lines of code probably. What's in it?

Comment: Did I read right? **35 MBs**? You should start by shifting common/similar code to utilities. Move hard-coded JSON to `.json` files

Answer (score 1):

If you add `async` to your script tag like this `<script async src="app.min.js"></script>` it will not block rendering anymore. Also caching the script in the browser or delivering it from a CDN can help reduce the download time.

35MB are, however, way too much for a website. Are you sure there isn't a lot of unused stuff like libraries in it?

We recently wrote an article with web performance best practices, with explanations to critical rendering path and other fronted concerns [here](https://medium.baqend.com/building-a-shop-with-sub-second-page-loads-lessons-learned-4bb1be3ed07#.diz5qdifn)

Comment: I'm not the one that created the js from unity, but i saw that a basic unity demo project will generate a 25MB file, minified, for webgl. The zipped file has around 7MB size

Comment: Wasn't are of that. But makes sense that a 3d game engine has a much bigger footprint. To maximize user experience I would build a landing page that shows some content to the user and load the big file async.

Answer (score 0):

35 MB just for the JS file seems ridiculous. It could be that the entire build is probably of that size (textures, media, etc.). Have a look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) on how to reduce the build size.

Answer (score 0):

Though **35 MB** is wayyyy to much for a JS file, you can start by following pointers:

- Create utilities and reuse the code. This can be at any level. Be it generic component (HTML generating code) or validation logic, if it can be configured using arguments, make a function and use it.
- If you have `Hard-coded` JSON in your js, move them to `.josn` files and load them only when they are required.
- Split files based on sections in view. In SPAs, there are cases when a section is not visible. For such cases, don't load such files. Spread your code base from 1 file to 100s of file.
- If you have a lot of event listeners, move them to different file. You can have `section_event.js`, `section_data.json`, `section_utils.js` and `section_index.js`. If there involves lot of data parsing, you can even have `section_parser.js`

Basic Idea is to split code into multiple files. Then, make code more reusable. You can even look into loading libraries to reduce your load.

Also, load a resource **only when required**. SPA have stages. Load concerned files when they are needed. Split download from 1 time to partial, on-demand approach. Also look into `webpack` or `grunt` or `gulp` to minify js.